# Using 10p,5p,2p and 1p coins to make 10 p where p stands for PENCE.

Tags: probability, permutations

Real question :

Show that you can make up 10 pence in eleven ways using 10p,5p,2p and 1p coins .

While doing a STEP problem, I came across this one. Just writing out possible outcomes gives me answer 11. But there is one particular comment on a book.

It says that this problem can be solved by finding the coeffiecient of $x^{10}$ in the following expression:
$$
{1\over(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x^2)(1-x)}
$$
I could not figure out how that problem can be converted into finding the coefficient of the above expression. Any information on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The 10p, etc. are names of coins, right? Keep in mind that might not be clear for everybody.

Comment: Sorry. P stands for p.

Comment: Also why do you have the whole thing in the denominator? And also, the $x^{10}$ term will only appear once in there. Make sure you haven't messed something up while writing this down here.

Comment: That is what I want to know as well .

Comment: That expression is absolutely correct .

Comment: You've written "...to make 10 coins..." To clarify: it asks for the ways to form a set of 10 coins from a stock of 4 different type coins? e.g. 10x 10p,  10x 1p, 5x 5p & 5x 2p,...?

Comment: Well. I think the question is self explanatory to be honest .

Comment: @AbuBardewa well, as a Brit (who speaks English) and passed STEP II & III and took my place at Cambridge, I can't understand the question. Hence my request for clarification. Nevermind. Good luck with it.

Comment: @ChrisKerridge I should probably write the exact question . I am sure that u know the booklet by Stephen Siklos. This problem is in that booklet . I will edit the question again.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give you just a sketch of the reason why that works.
You must take into account first of all the formal series expansion:
$$
\tag{a}
{1\over 1-t}=1+t+t^3+t^3+\ldots
$$

Suppose you represent a total sum of $n$ pence by $x^n$, so that to combine two or more coins of values $a$ and $b$ to get a total of $a+b$ pence you just have to multiply the powers: $x^a\cdot x^b=x^{a+b}$.

With only 10p coins you can get 0, 10, 20, … pence and you can represent that as an infinite polynomial $1+x^{10}+x^{20}+x^{30}+\ldots={1\over1-x^{10}}$ where I have used (a) to write that in a compact form. The same goes for the other coins, so that all the possible combinations of your coins are given by the product of all those polynomials, which is just
$\displaystyle{1\over(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x^2)(1-x)}$.

By using (a) with $t=(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x^2)(1-x)-1$, this can be written as an infinite polynomial:
$$
{1\over(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x^2)(1-x)}=
1+x+2 x^2+2 x^3+3 x^4+4 x^5+5 x^6+6 x^7+7 x^8+8 x^9+11 x^{10}
+12 x^{11}+\ldots
$$
The coefficient of $x^{10}$ will then give you the number of different combinations of coins which can be combined to give 10 pence.

Comment: Perfect . This was what I needed . Thanks a lot .